# Accessing datastore using Cursor after migration to HRD

Tags: java, google-app-engine

After a migration to **HRD** datastore, I'm getting some errors related to some datastore access using [Cursor](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Cursor):

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: query app is 's~appid-hrd' but cursor.position.key app is 'appid'
```

Where:

- `appid-hrd` is the new application id (*Note:* there is a `s~` suffix in the application id)
- `appid` is the old application id

I guess that I'm missing some change in the `appengine-web.xml` but I couldn't find any documentation related to this problem.

Thanks,

Comment: A similar error is posted in the forum thread https://groups.google.com/d/msg/codereview-discuss/dhvPVmtMtC8/a7KVS7iAfBgJ and the reply is: _Yeah, let's just ignore that. It will go away eventually_